# Проблемы с двоеточием в ID, которое посылается для обработки jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.
У меня такая проблемка с `jQuery`: Если я пытаюсь при помощи `jQuery` обратиться к элементу с ID в котором есть двоеточие (:), то выдается ошибка. Как я узнал, `jQuery` определяет двоеточие как разделитель. Может кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы двоеточия в моих айдишниках `jQuery` не определял как особые символы?
Вот пример банального кода, при котором `jQuery` отказывается спрятать картинку:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
    Страница HTML
</TITLE>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#ee:pole").hide();
        });
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <img id="ee:pole" src="orange-barber-pole.gif"></img>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**PS**: Использовать двоеточия в названиях у меня обязательно. Т.к. я работаю с JSF2, который в ID сам автоматически ставит "Название_формы:мой_ID".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       jQuery('#ee\\:pole').hide();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо перед двоеточием или другим знаком, которого `jQuery` определяет как разделитель, ставить "\\".

Answer (score 0):

А чем Вас не устраивает `document.getElementById('')`?
Он никакие двоеточия как разделитель не воспринимает.

В Вашем случае, если необходимо использование `jQuery('').hide()`, код выглядел бы так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var pole = document.getElementById('#ee:pole');
            if (pole) { jQuery(pole).hide(); }
        });
</script>
```

PS: Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой, но подставлять перед двоеточием двойной обратный слеш у меня нет возможности.